# MySQL statement to query each result separately

Tags: mysql

Im trying to query a wordpress database where each of the values for each user is stored on a different row.

For example

```
ID  USER_ID FIELD_ID  VALUE
1      1       2        my name is paul smith
2      1       3        i bought books
3      1       4        online
4      2       2        my name is big boy
5      2       3        i bought pens
6      2       4        offline
```

here you can see instead of a field name, its a FIELD_ID, so FIELD_ID=2 means user name and FIELD_ID=3 means what they bought, and FIELD_ID=4 means they are on/off line.

What i need to do is to make ONE sql statement that returns a list of users that are online right now who bought pens.

so i tried doing this

select all users whose field_id=4 and value='online'

```
 string online= "(select * from table where FIELD_ID='4' AND VALUE='online')";
```

select all users whose field_id 3 contains 'pens'

```
 string pens="(select * from table where FIELD_ID='3' AND VALUE LIKE '%pens%'";
```

Then put them together like this

```
string query=pens + " WHERE " + online;
```

if i run the "online" and "pens" sql statement by themselves it works, but the combined "query" doesnt return anything.

I guess it could be because the "online" query result will include a bunch of USER_IDs of users who are online now, but then the second query have to run a query on each of the USER_IDs from that and return the value.

so somehow it has to know to select the USER_ID field from the "online" query and then query each of those USER_ID separately and send back the combined result.

I got no clue how to make just ONE SQL statement to do all that in one shot and just send back the users who are online now who bought pens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that the table includes a USER_ID. If so, then a way to combine the two queries follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIELD_ID='4' AND VALUE='online' AND USER_ID IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM table WHERE FIELD_ID='3' AND VALUE LIKE '%pens%');
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i will try those!!

Comment: Thanks so much CaitLAN, that FREEKING WORKED!!!!! thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks!

Comment: i dont know what i would do without the users on stack overflow, i would be so screwed!!!

Comment: I am happy to assist. If you are satisfied with this particular response, please mark it as the answer so that the question is resolved and removed from the unanswered questions feed.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, you just need to make your subquery return the ids of the users and then use an `IN` statement, example pseudocode:

```
... WHERE id IN ([subquery])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join

```
Select *
From (
    Select *
    FROM Table
    WHERE FIELD_ID='4' AND VALUE='online'
) t
WHERE t.FIELD_ID='3' AND t.VALUE LIKE '%pens%'
```

Comment: This isn't a join, but it works for what the OP seems to want to do.

Comment: Yea, I dont know why I said join...it's been a long morning.